# Set.prototype.has() with predicate

Tags: javascript

```js
var myset = new Set();
    
myset.add({ key: 123, value: 100 });
var has = myset.has({ key: 123, value: 100 });    
console.log(has); // false
       
var obj = {
    key: 456,
    value: 200
};

myset.add(obj);
has = myset.has(obj);
console.log(has); // true
    
has = myset.has(x => x.key === 123);    
console.log(has); // false
```

The problem in this case: I just add `{ key: 123, value: 100 }` to `myset`, why doesn't it contain `{ key: 123, value: 100 }`?

Another case, if I use `obj` instead of `{ key: 123, value: 100 }`, it would return `true`.

[Set.prototype.has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) says:

> The has() method returns a boolean indicating whether an element with the specified value exists in a Set object or not.

But that doesn't mention about: what's `specified value`?

Clearly, in this case `{ key: 123, value: 100 }` and `{ key: 123, value: 100 }` are similar to, and.... I'm getting `false`. So what's `specified` here?

And the second question: why doesn't they support `predicate` in `has()` method?

In my example. It's harder to search if I use `for...of...`:

```
for (let obj of myset) {
    if (obj.key === 123) return true;
}
```

While it can be inline with predicating:

```
has = myset.has(x => x.key === 123)
```

So, should it be improved for future?

Comment: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/maps-with-object-keys yup, sorry. JS maps are broken for practical use cases and the person who said he'll fix them is not going to. It doesn't support predicates or structural equality because working on a language is ungrateful work that requires thousands of hours and most people are not willing to put that in.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ya. Thanks! I'm waiting for ECMAScript 2018 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Set.prototype.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) doesn't find the object because it tests using [value equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality), meaning:

```
{ key: 123 } !== { key: 123 } // true
```

If you want to be able to find an item based on a predicate, you will have to add that function manually. The function probably doesn't exist already because a `Set` is only efficient when you need fast lookups without iteration. If you want to iterate values, use an array instead.

Here's how you could implement it just as [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
Set.prototype.find = function () {
    return Array.prototype.find.apply([...this], arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`{ key: 123, value: 100 } === { key: 123, value: 100 }` is `false` because JavaScript performs a shallow comparison. Each object literal creates a new object, they may hold the same values, but they are still different objects that just happens to look alike.

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
a === b; // true
```

In this example you get `true` because now you are comparing the same object. You can tell that `a`, and `b` are the same object because changes in `a` are reflected in `b`.

```
a.x = 1;
b.x === 1; // true
```

`myset.has(x => x.key === 123)` here you are asking if the set has this new lambda that you just created. It would be nice if `has` used your lambda to check the elements of the set, but unfortunately the method does perform this check.